# Is there a way to force a perfectly overlapping x and y axis corner in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

Here is a very simple example plot that illustrates the problem I am having:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + theme_classic()
 + geom_point()  + theme(axis.line = element_line(size = 3))
```

yields this:
[image: output of ggplot2 code]

You can see how I've manually circled the corner where the axes don't intersect nicely; I would like them to perfectly overlap. I made these axes especially heavy to emphasize the problem but it is there when thinner lines are used as well.  I haven't found anything in the ggplot2 documentation or anywhere else online that addresses this. Does anyone know any way of making the axes intersect in a perfect corner? This can be overcome if there happens to be an y axis tick on the bottom but I don't want to rely on this.  I also know that I can just use `theme_grey` but I sometimes prefer themes that just use axes to define the plot area.